# UV unwrapping proportion problem

Tags: uv

I'm new to this, have seen some tutorials about unwrapping box...but when I unwrap it, final result doesn't seems to be in proportional rate.
What am I doing wrong? Please see in the attached picture.

Thank you so much for your help!
J.

[image]

Comment: You need to apply scale to your object. Ctrl + A in object mode.